# How to unembed images in Indesign CC 2015

Tags: adobe-indesign, images, embed

I have created a document where many of the images have been embedded.

**Now I want to unembed them.**

My issue is that the LINK panel in Indesign CC seems to not any more show embed assets, only Linked assets are there, so I don't know how to transform my images from Embedded to Linked assets.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

With InDesign, generally the reason an image is not displayed in the Links panel is because it has been pasted into InDesign.

The script available at the page below will extract pasted (and embedded) images. See here:
http://www.kahrel.plus.com/indesign/unembed_images.html

It was created by [Peter Kahrel](http://www.oreilly.com/pub/au/2758).

And, in case running scripts is unfamiliar, he also explains how to [install and run scripts](http://www.kahrel.plus.com/indesign/script-info.html#download_install).